# Node JS Sequelize how to count associations data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize as ORM in node JS. In have two taboes. Event and Comment. And I make an association like this : Event has many comments. Now i want to retreive all the events and count the number of comments of each event.
For now I do this :

```
 db.Event.findAndCountAll({limit: limit,offset: offset, include: [ db.Comment], order: 'date DESC'}).
```

and next return

```
JSON.stringify(result.rows).
```

How can I retrun the number of the comments with only one query.

Please Help me.

Thanky you in advance

Comment: With or without a `limit` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The "result" you will return is the one passed to the success callback function, right?

```
db.Event.findAndCountAll(...).success(
    function(result) { // this guy
        console.log(result.count) //this logs the count
    }
)
```

You can use result.count to get the value

Answer (score 0):

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM event AS e JOIN comment AS c ON (c.event_id = e.id)').success(function(result) {
 console.log("Total count", result.count)
}).error(function(err) {
 console.error(err)
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

You always can perform a raw SQL query.

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM event AS e JOIN comment AS c ON (c.event_id = e.id)').success(function(result) {

}).error(function(err) {

});
```